# Repartitioning to install Linux on an NTFS disk

Tags: linux, partitioning, ntfs

[EDITED to clarify]
I have 2 physical disks, both NTFS. One has Windows installed and the second is just for data. I want to:

1. Resize the secondary NTFS disk leaving half of it unallocated.
2. Partition and format the newly unallocated part of the disk so it may be used to boot Linux.
3. Make sure the disk is bootable since my other drive will be my primary disk for now.

How can I repartition and install linux on the second disk?

I apologize for this very common problem... I just can't seem to find an answer to this particular question.

Comment: what about http://gparted.org/livecd.php

Comment: If you want to install Linux on an NTFS file system, I do not think this is possible due to NTFS not supporting Linux file permissions. You need to create partitions on the disk for the Linux installation; usually, you will have three partitions for the Linux installation: '/', '/boot' and swap. These can be made with a disk partitioning tool (see. comment by user993553).

Comment: Which distro would you like to install?

Answer (score 1):

I may as well answer my own stupid question since it's quite simple:

1. Back up your files
2. Open Disk Management (Run diskmgmt.msc)
3. Right click the volume you want to resize.
4. Select 'Shrink Volume...'
5. Enter the amount you want to subtract from your currently partitioned volume in "Enter the amount of space to shrink in MB:"
6. Reboot
7. Set up your partitions using gparted OR just leave it the Linux installer.
8. Enjoy.

LOL. Thanks for everyone who commented and helped me along the way!